# Combining two fractions involing powers of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, partial-fractions

Is there any way i can write

$x^a+x^b$ as d$x^c$

Im considering writing letting $a=a-1$ and partial fractions but im getting really confused.

Comment: Assume $b-a=d$. Then $x^a+ x^b = x^a+ x^{a+d}=x^a+...$

Comment: To be sure: d is a constant?

Comment: Yes, d is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

It is (near) never true: $x^a+x^b=x^a(1+x^{b-a})$ and the expression in the parentheses is not of the form $Ax^E$, because limit in the infinity shows that $A=1$, $E=b-a$, but then, e.g. for $x=0$, the expressions are different.